# nodetool command not working in cassandra version 2.2.3?

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I have a problem with cassandra nodetool. My question is:

When I type `nodetool status` command, it is not working. The output is:

> Starting NodeTool

Does anybody have clue why it is not working?

NB : my cassandra version is `2.2.3`

Comment: Any chance your using jdk 11? 2.2.3 was released nearly 4 years ago and doesn't work with that. Most likely though is that your jmx ports are not open

Comment: how can i open jmx port? and how install jmx?? - i use cassandra 2.2.3 version for opscenter, i mean when use cassandra 3, can't use opscenter